# Project Structure

Tags: structure, project

What is preferrable project internal structure for designing API based task.

1) Application will create API which will be acting as consumer and provider both 2) As a consumer it will integrate with multiple systems 3) Integration Systems can be SOAP based or SOA based

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question which structure should the project have, you should define first:

- if project is oriented on business requirements and they are being changed quite often, then it's SOA based architecture. The main difference between Service-Oriented (SOA) and Service-Based Architecture is that SOA had a "message-bus" layer, which translates business requirements to existing architecture. Service-Oriented architecture has similar topology to Microservice architecture, but services are more task/project oriented, not as small as in microservice;
- if project has clear vision how API should look like and can define as a part of a tech specification, then first create an API, and then build other systems around;
- second option you mentioned (As a consumer it will integrate with multiple systems) depends on project's needs, hard to say without knowing tech specifications.